# How to get declared symbol from SemanticModel for newly created class?

Tags: c#, roslyn, .net-4.6

What is the easiest way to get an `ISymbol` from a `ClassDeclaration` that I just created?

Consider the following code:

```
AdhocWorkspace workspace = new AdhocWorkspace();         
Project project = workspace.AddProject("Test", LanguageNames.CSharp);

ClassDeclarationSyntax classDeclaration = SyntaxFactory.ClassDeclaration("MyClass");
CompilationUnitSyntax compilationUnit = SyntaxFactory.CompilationUnit().AddMembers(classDeclaration);         
Document document = project.AddDocument("Test.cs", compilationUnit);
SemanticModel semanticModel = await document.GetSemanticModelAsync();
ISymbol symbol = semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(classDeclaration); // <-- Throws Exception
```

The last line throws an exception saying "**Syntax node is not within syntax tree**".

I assume I need to get the `ClassDeclarationSyntax` that I just created again from the new `SyntaxTree`. But what is the easiest way to find it in the new `SyntaxTree` given that I only have the old `ClassDeclarationSyntax`?

In the example above the class is the only class in the `SyntaxTree` and is the first child of the `CompilationUnit`, so it would be easy to find in this simple case. But imagine a situation where the syntax tree contains a lot of declarations, that may be nested, and the sought after class declaration is nested deep within? Is there some way to use the old `ClassDeclarationSyntax` to find the new one? (Or am I going about things all wrong here?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a [`SyntaxAnnotation`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Syntax/SyntaxAnnotation.cs,5df4388ff3239a2c) to keep track of your class nodes:

```
AdhocWorkspace workspace = new AdhocWorkspace();
Project project = workspace.AddProject("Test", LanguageNames.CSharp);

//Attach a syntax annotation to the class declaration
var syntaxAnnotation = new SyntaxAnnotation("ClassTracker");
var classDeclaration = SyntaxFactory.ClassDeclaration("MyClass")
    .WithAdditionalAnnotations(syntaxAnnotation);

var compilationUnit = SyntaxFactory.CompilationUnit().AddMembers(classDeclaration);

Document document = project.AddDocument("Test.cs", compilationUnit);
SemanticModel semanticModel = document.GetSemanticModelAsync().Result;

//Use the annotation on our original node to find the new class declaration
var changedClass = document.GetSyntaxRootAsync().Result.DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>()
    .Where(n => n.HasAnnotation(syntaxAnnotation)).Single();
var symbol = semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(changedClass);
```

This should work no matter what kind of complex documents you end up adding your class to.

Comment: How do you do this when you didn't _create_ the syntax node? I have found a syntax node and I need to find it again after a transformation. But when I call `WithAdditionalAnnotations` on the node before the mutation, the syntax node I get back has no `Parent`.

Comment: @AndrewArnott I think you need to find your node and its parent first. Then call `WithAdditionalAnnotations()` and save that node. I think you could then then call `parent.ReplaceNode(newNodeWithAnnotations)`.

Comment: @AndrewArnott It's also possible the `DocumentEditor` or a `CSharpSyntaxRewriter` may be better suited for your purposes. I find them easier to use when applying a large number of changes to a syntax tree.

Comment: @JoshVarty can I somehow create new .csproj and sln programmatically with Roslyn and save it to file?

Comment: @Konrad as far as I know you cannot add/save new `.csproj` or `.sln` with Roslyn. See: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/6825
From what I recall they would accept community contributions on this issue, but aren't working on it themselves.